# preventing timestamp creation in to_datetime() formatting in order to group by periods

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime

My pandas `df3` is very large and roughly looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['23.02.2012', '23.02.2012', 'aaa'], ['27.02.2014', '27.02.2014', 'bbb'], ['17.08.2018', '17.08.2018', 'ccc'], ['22.07.2019', '22.07.2019', 'ddd']], columns=['date', 'period', 'text'])
```

I want to make column `period` display the following periods if the dates correspond

```
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date'], errors = 'coerce')
df3['period'] = df3['date']
col_name = 'period'
strt_col = df3.pop(col_name)
df3.insert(5, col_name, strt_col)

mask1 = (df3['date'] >= '1990-10-14') & (df3['date'] < '1994-11-10')
mask2 = (df3['date'] >= '1994-11-10') & (df3['date'] < '1999-10-1')
mask3 = (df3['date'] >= '1999-10-1') & (df3['date'] < '2004-6-13')
mask4 = (df3['date'] >= '2004-6-13') & (df3['date'] < '2009-8-30')
mask5 = (df3['date'] >= '2009-8-30') & (df3['date'] < '2014-10-14')
mask6 = (df3['date'] >= '2014-10-14') & (df3['date'] < '2019-11-26')
mask7 = (df3['date'] >= '2019-11-26') & (df3['date'] < '2021-9-20')
df3.loc[mask1, 'period'] = '1990-1994'
df3.loc[mask2, 'period'] = '1994-1999'
df3.loc[mask3, 'period'] = '1999-2004'
df3.loc[mask4, 'period'] = '2004-2009'
df3.loc[mask5, 'period'] = '2009-2014'
df3.loc[mask6, 'period'] = '2014-2019'
df3.loc[mask7, 'period'] = '2019-2021'

df3 = df3.sort_values(by = ['period'])
.
.
.
```

throws at `df3 = df3.sort_values(by = ['period'])`

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`

If i run the code until `df3.loc[mask7, 'period'] = '2019-2021'` the output looks as follows:

col 'period' has `1994-1999` and 'date' has clean `10/2/1998`

So far so good for 99,9 % of the rows.

**Problem:** Exactly 100 rows have col 'period' `10/2/2021  12:00:00 AM` and col 'date' has **clean** `10/2/2021`

**Desired output** for col 'period': `2019-2021`

Even though the 'date' value is clean and in the right format (i double checked that, there are no other characters in that cell), it is subsequently not formatted the way all other rows are. Why?

Here are all of the `date` cells (day/month/year) that were the source of the false formatting:

```
'date' after to_datetime()
10/2/2021
10/2/2021
10/2/2021
10/2/2021
10/3/2021
10/3/2021
10/3/2021
10/3/2021
10/3/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/5/2021
10/6/2021
10/6/2021
11/1/2021
11/1/2021
11/1/2021
11/1/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/2/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/3/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/5/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
11/6/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/1/2021
12/2/2021
12/2/2021
12/2/2021
12/3/2021
12/3/2021
12/4/2021
12/4/2021
12/5/2021
12/5/2021

'period'    
10/2/2021 0:00
10/2/2021 0:00
10/2/2021 0:00
10/2/2021 0:00
10/3/2021 0:00
10/3/2021 0:00
10/3/2021 0:00
10/3/2021 0:00
10/3/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/5/2021 0:00
10/6/2021 0:00
10/6/2021 0:00
11/1/2021 0:00
11/1/2021 0:00
11/1/2021 0:00
11/1/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/2/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/3/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/5/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
11/6/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/1/2021 0:00
12/2/2021 0:00
12/2/2021 0:00
12/2/2021 0:00
12/3/2021 0:00
12/3/2021 0:00
12/4/2021 0:00
12/4/2021 0:00
12/5/2021 0:00
12/5/2021 0:00
```

I added `df3['question_date'].dt.date` after `pd.to_datetime` which resulted in the following error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting by `\n` and using the first element ? This will "clean" the data.

Something like the below:

```
val1 = '27.02.2014\nwer'
val2 = '27.02.2014'

date1 = val1.split('\n')[0]
date2 = val2.split('\n')[0]
print(date1)
print(date2)
```

output

```
27.02.2014
27.02.2014
```

Comment: at `df3 = df3.sort_values(by = ['period'])`
throws error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: what if there's no newline, maybe just some characters?

Comment: OP - please share more "dirty" dates example so we can extend the solution.

Comment: thats the problem, as i have pointed out in the comments of Mr.Fuppes answer. I would like to but cannot find any deviations. I identified the dirty `date` rows and removed them alltogether. I added what i tried to the question above.