# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

My pandas `df3` looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['23.02.2012', '23.02.2012', 'aaa'], ['27.02.2014', '27.02.2014', 'bbb'], ['17.08.2018', '17.08.2018', 'ccc'], ['22.07.2019', '22.07.2019', 'ddd']], columns=['date', 'period', 'text'])
```

I want to make column `period` display the following periods if the dates correspond. Since some `date` values were formatted with timestamp and some not, it didnt create the correct (without timestamp) `period` values. That is why i did `df3['question_date'].dt.date`

```
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date'], errors = 'coerce')
df3['question_date'] = df3['question_date']
df3['period'] = df3['date']
col_name = 'period'
strt_col = df3.pop(col_name)
df3.insert(5, col_name, strt_col)

date1 = pd.Timestamp('1990-10-14').date()
date2 = pd.Timestamp('1994-11-10').date()
date3 = pd.Timestamp('1999-10-1').date()
date4 = pd.Timestamp('2004-6-13').date()
date5 = pd.Timestamp('2009-8-30').date()
date6 = pd.Timestamp('2014-10-14').date()
date7 = pd.Timestamp('2019-11-26').date()
date8 = pd.Timestamp('2021-9-20').date()
mask1 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date1') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date2')
mask2 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date2') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date3')
mask3 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date3') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date4')
mask4 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date4') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date5')
mask5 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date5') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date6')
mask6 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date6') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date7')
mask7 = (df3['question_date'] >= 'date7') & (df3['question_date'] < 'date8')
df3.loc[mask1, 'leg_per'] = '1990-1994'
df3.loc[mask2, 'leg_per'] = '1994-1999'
df3.loc[mask3, 'leg_per'] = '1999-2004'
df3.loc[mask4, 'leg_per'] = '2004-2009'
df3.loc[mask5, 'leg_per'] = '2009-2014'
df3.loc[mask6, 'leg_per'] = '2014-2019'
df3.loc[mask7, 'leg_per'] = '2019-2021'
.
.
.
```

At `mask1` it throws error

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Original question: [preventing timestamp creation in to_datetime() formatting in order to group by periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358058/preventing-timestamp-creation-in-to-datetime-formatting-in-order-to-group-by-d)

Comment: `df3['date']` is a date object, and `'1990-10-14'` is a string.  You can't compare those two values directly.  Convert one of them so they are the same type.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong.  You can't use the `>=` operator to compare between a `datetime.date` object and a `str` object.  You need to either convert the date to a string, or the string to a date.

Comment: pd.to_datetime converts to datetime64, not datetime.date - how come you have instances of that class?

Comment: i read that somewhere else. Does the separator matter? I still get the same error. the `date1` has `-` while the `date` values are separated by `/`

Comment: Doing `df3['question_date'].dt.date` ensures i dont have timestamps. if i dont do `.date()` subsequently, it would result in `1990-10-14 00:00:00` format with timestamps, that caused the `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`error (see original question) in the first place.

Comment: In general, if you work with date/time in pandas, and want to save yourself some trouble: use the datetime64 data type pandas has to offer. Avoid Python's datetime, date and time class. It will cause issues as the one you're experiencing and reduce functionality you have at hand.

Comment: so simply write `date1 = pd.Timestamp('1990-10-14')` and the mask like `mask1 = (df3['question_date'] >= date1) & (df3['question_date'] < date2)`, with `df3['question_date']` being a pandas datetime64 column.

Comment: throws `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str`. `date.dtype` returns `datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slighly modified version of your example,

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame([['23.02.2012', 'aaa'], ['27.02.2014', 'bbb'], 
                    ['17.08.2018', 'ccc'], ['22.07.2019', 'ddd']], 
                   columns=['date', 'text'])

# ensure datetime64[ns] type
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Note that for given date/time format in the example, you [need to specify that the day comes first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69255327/10197418) if you don't provide a `format`. Also, use `errors='coerce'` only if you're know what you're doing - I always prefer errors to be raised first.

Now let's create a mask for a certain date range. Note that `pandas` is clever enough that you can use dates as strings (see also [Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing), can be applied to comparisons as well):

```
date1 = '2010-10-14'
date2 = '2014-11-10'
m = (df3['date'] >= '2010-10-14') & (df3['date'] < '2014-11-10')

df3.loc[m, 'leg_per'] = '2010-2014'
```

The dummy df then looks like

```
df3
        date text    leg_per
0 2012-02-23  aaa  2010-2014
1 2014-02-27  bbb  2010-2014
2 2018-08-17  ccc        NaN
3 2019-07-22  ddd        NaN
```

---

In general, if you work with date/time in pandas, and want to save yourself some trouble: use the datetime64 data type pandas has to offer. Avoid Python's datetime, date and time class. It will cause issues as the one you're experiencing and reduce functionality you have at hand.