# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to run this in Jupyter Notebook:

```
isolated = diff['2012-09-28' <= diff['start_date']]
isolated
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

What should I do? I already tried importing pandas and datetime but it didn't work.

Comment: Since `'2012-09-28'` is a string you should convert it to a `datetime.date` type. [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) should work fine.

Comment: How do I convert it to a datetime.date type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69378514/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-datetime-date-and-str)

Comment: What is `diff`? I thought it was a Pandas DataFrame, but I can't reproduce the issue unless I set it up in a really weird way (convert to `datetime.date` but cast to `object`). Please make a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. You can [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Convert column to datetimes:

```
diff['2012-09-28' <= pd.to_datetime(diff['start_date'])]
```

Or convert string to date:

```
diff[pd.Timestamp('2012-09-28').date() <= diff['start_date']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The 1st one worked properly.

Answer (score -1):

Strings cannot be compared directly; they need to convert to suitable data format for comparison.

**Use this sort of formatting.**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
startdate = pd.to_datetime("date").date()
enddate = pd.to_datetime("date").date()
```